# How to count uppercase vowels and lowercase vowels in a string?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have create a program in java to count lowercase vowels and uppercase vowels in a string. but the out put is not showing in right way.

my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vowelscount {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give a string ");
        String input=keyboard.nextLine();
        char []chars=input.toCharArray();



        int upperCase = 0;
        int lowerCase = 0;
        int vowelcount=0;
        for(char c : chars) {

            switch(c){
            case 'a':case 'A':
            case 'e':case 'E':
            case 'i':case 'I':
            case 'o':case 'O':
            case 'u':case 'U':
                vowelcount++;
                break;

            }

        }
        for (int k = 0; k < input.length(); k++) {
            // Check for upper case letters.
            if (Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(k))) upperCase++;

            // Check for lower case letters.
            if (Character.isLowerCase(input.charAt(k))) lowerCase++;
        }

        System.out.printf("There are %d uppercase letters and %d lowercase letters.",upperCase,lowerCase);
        System.out.printf("Number of vowels="+vowelcount);

}}
```

Comment: "_out put is not showing in right way_" You should provide us an example of what the output is supposed to look like and what it actually looks like.

Comment: question, can a letter be upper case and also lower case at the same time? perhaps an if/else will suffice? :)

Comment: Your code give the required and mentioned output. If there any other way that you expect please mention it.

Answer (score 3):

This can be easly done using java 8 features:

```
String str = "lalfalk;jwerLSKJDFLKJWEROIURE";

long upperCase = str.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)                // getting Stream<Character> with each char in the String
        .filter(c -> "AEIOU".indexOf(c) > -1)   // filter just to leave the upper case vowels
        .count();                               // count the number of vowels found in the String

// using the same logic
long lowerCase = str.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
        .filter(c -> "aeiou".indexOf(c) > -1)
        .count();

// the total number of vowels is the sum of the number of upper and lower found in the string
long vowelcount = upperCase + lowerCase;

System.out.printf("There are %d uppercase letters and %d lowercase letters. ", upperCase, lowerCase);
System.out.printf("Number of vowels = " + vowelcount);
```

output:

> There are 5 uppercase letters and 3 lowercase letters. Number of
>   vowels = 8

Comment: That's very cool, but might be a bit over his head.

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop does not filter consonants. So first you need to check if the character is a vowel and then check if it is upper or lower case.

```
for (int k = 0; k < input.length(); k++) 
{
    if("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(input.charAt(k)) != -1)
    {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(k))) upperCase++;

            // Check for lower case letters.
            if (Character.isLowerCase(input.charAt(k))) lowerCase++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you counting not only the vowels, you can just use the select case to count uppercase and lowercase as well, check out the code below. I have modified your code a little bit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vowelscount {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give a string ");
        String input=keyboard.nextLine();
        char []chars=input.toCharArray();
        int upperCase = 0;
        int lowerCase = 0;
        int vowelcount=0;
        for(char c : chars) {
            switch(c){
               case 'a':
               case 'e':
               case 'i':
               case 'o':
               case 'u':
                  vowelcount++;
                  lowerCase++;
                  break;
               case 'A':
               case 'E':
               case 'I':
               case 'O':
               case 'U':
                  vowelcount++;
                  upperCase++;
                  break;
           }  

        }

        System.out.printf("There are %d uppercase letters and %d lowercase letters.",upperCase,lowerCase);
        System.out.printf("Number of vowels="+vowelcount);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u for your suggestion but how to get out put, if i want to count each vowels character in lowercase and uppercase, for example A: lowercase and upper case and total appearance of A,a in a string and E: lowercase and upper case and total appearance of E,e in a string same as each vowel need to display. kindly looking for your help...

Comment: You could use a hash map to count each vowel's appearance. Look up hash maps in Java if you are not familiar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some Java 8 streams quite easily:

```
@Test
public void shouldCountUpperAndLowerCaseVowels() {
    final String input = "Some test INPUT string";
    final Long upper = input.chars().filter(i -> Arrays.asList('A','E','I','O','U').contains((char)i)).count();
    final Long lower = input.chars().filter(i -> Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u').contains((char)i)).count();
    System.out.printf("Vowels:%nUppercase: %d%nLowercase: %d%nTotal: %s%n", upper, lower, upper + lower);
}
```

Output:

> Vowels:
>
> Uppercase: {uc}
>
> Lowercase: {lc}
>
> Total: {uc + lc}

Comment: Your code will have some difficulty compiling.

Comment: What is `Collections.newArrayList`?

Comment: Ah sorry about that, wrote it in a rushed lunch hour.  So the Collections.newArrayList was an import from the flapdoodle library for running an in-memory version of MongoDB.  Just changed it to use Arrays.asList so no external libraries and corrected the variable use from string to input.